# Where to store a file for all users to access

Tags: cocoa

I have a file that I want all users on a computer to have access to. I don't want to have to duplicate it in each user's specific path. I don't want to have to elevate the app's permissions. Is there a place on the computer (no icloud or webspace) that I can save it where everyone can read/write it?

Comment: Both answers below are right depending on what you need your users to do with the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/Users/Shared` folder is the place that is designed for this.  It exists if there is more than one account on a Mac

See [How to Use the Shared Folder in OS X](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/how-to-use-the-shared-folder-in-os-x) for what you can do with it

Comment: @joels - By default files written here by one user will not be able to be *written* by another. You'll need to look into the "umask" if you need to support this from an application.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/Library/Application Support`

From [Mac App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/AppRuntime/AppRuntime.html)

> If the resources apply to all users on the system, such as document
>   templates, place them in /Library/Application Support.

Comment: I would have to elevate the app's permissions to write to that directory